# How to type a ref parameter with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript and I'm currently trying to migrate one of my React.js projects to Typescript. One of the things I stumble on are `refs`. I have written a hook that is using a `ref` as a paremeter. Basically it detects if there is a click outside of a div and fire a function that's passed as second parameter. Now I'm wondering how I can type that specific `ref`. I've tried different solutions such as `React.RefObject<any>` but don't think using `any` would be a good idea? What can I use instead? The value is either `undefined` or a div (Container component is styled component), see code:

Hook

```
// How to type `ref`?
export function useOnClickOutside(ref: React.RefObject<any>, handler: Function) {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const listener = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {
        // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
        if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
          return
        }

        handler(event)
      }

      // MouseEvent
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener)
      // TouchEvent
      document.addEventListener('touchstart', listener)

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener)
        document.removeEventListener('touchstart', listener)
      }
    },
    // Add ref and handler to effect dependencies
    [ref, handler]
  )
}
```

Component

```
  const containerRef = React.useRef()
  useOnClickOutside(containerRef, () => setIsOpen(false))

  // Some code

  <Container ref={containerRef}>
    // Some code
  </Container
```

So basically: What should `<any>` be instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use **<HTMLDivElement>** as mentioned in https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-refs-with-typescript-a32d56c4d315

Comment: Is it optional or you will get always?

Comment: `ref.current.contains(event.target)` this means your ref should be typed to have a `contains` method that takes a `HTMLElement` as input, I.E. the ref is to a `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 9):

the only part that is related to the type of the ref is this line:

```
    if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
```

This means the ref is something that has a `contains` method that takes as input a `EventTarget | null` object, so the minimum you would need to make it work is this:

```
interface ValidRefTarget {
  contains(target: EventTarget | null): any;
}

export function useOnClickOutside(ref: React.RefObject<ValidRefTarget>, handler: (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent)=>void ) {
```

However since this method is provided by the `HTMLElement` object you probably want to just use that instead:

```
export function useOnClickOutside(ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>, handler: (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent)=>void ) {
```

Comment: RefObject<HTMLElement> works perfectly when typing props, thank you.

Comment: Does this work for refs defined as functions?

Comment: @k3liutZu not sure I understand what you mean, but in general you pass the type of data you expect to keep a reference to to the generic of `RefObject`, so it might look something like `RefObject<(a:string) => void>` but that depends on your use case.